# (CSS) Strange white border around menu that isn't a border

Tags: html, css, menu

I have just created my first multi-level drop-down menu, but have some problems with two white borders. The first white border is at the bottom of the menu that seems to be related to the padding of the a-elements. I have marked the place in the script below.

The second white border is around the drop-down menu with languages. I have experimented with a lot of different alternatives but haven't so far found any solutions to these problem(s).

Here you can see the menu:

```css
#menu-1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#menu-1 .top-border {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 1px;
}

#menu-1 .top-border .logo {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  width: auto;
  height: 62px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#menu-1 .top-border .contact-info {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.main-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.translation-services-usa.com/images/quote-admin/main_menu_background.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  min-height: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.menu-item {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.main-navigation a {
  font-size: 9.5px;
  letter-spacing: .0625em;
  font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  /* Padding below creates the white border */
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #146;
  border-right: 1px solid #024;
}

.sub-menu-item a {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 10px 13px 10px 13px;
}

.right-arrow {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 13px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #035;
}

li:hover li {
  float: none;
}

.sub-menu-1 a {
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #041e37;
  border-left: 1px solid #002244;
  border-right: 1px solid #002244;
}

.menu-item-2 {
  font-size: 11px!important;
  border-left: none!important;
  border-right: none!important;
  padding-top: 11px!important;
}

.main-navigation li ul li {
  border-top: 0;
}

ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-1">

  <div class="top-border">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/SEGA_logo.png" class="logo" alt="Scandinavia">


    <div class="contact-info">
      <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/iso-png-iso-png-1000.png" style="height: 37px; width: auto; padding-right: 10px;" alt="Scandinavia">
      <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/iso-png-iso-png-1000.png" style="height: 37px; width: auto; padding-right: 8px;" alt="Scandinavia">
      <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/iso-png-iso-png-1000.png" style="height: 39px; width: auto;" alt="Scandinavia">
    </div>

  </div>

  <ul class="main-navigation">
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">ITEM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">ITEM <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-1">
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT <i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT<i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT<i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">ITEM <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-1">
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">ITEM <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-1">
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>



    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">ITEM <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-1">
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT <i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT <i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT <i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT<i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>



    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">ITEM <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-1">
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT <i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#">TEXT<i class="right-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item" style="border-right: none;">ITEM</a></li>




    <!-- <img src="images/eng.png" /> -->


    <li style="float: right;">


      <a href="#" class="menu-item-2"><img src="https://www.translation-services-usa.com/images/main-menu-flag-en.png" style="margin-bottom: 0.5px; vertical-align: middle;" /> English</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu-1">
        <li class="sub-menu-item">
          <!-- Dubbel dropdown -->
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.translation-services-usa.com/images/main-menu-flag-en.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> English</a>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.translation-services-usa.com/images/main-menu-flag-en.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> English</a>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.translation-services-usa.com/images/main-menu-flag-en.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> English</a>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.translation-services-usa.com/images/main-menu-flag-en.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> English</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas on solutions? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `remove box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px -2px rgba` from `menu-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`white border` outside menu is come from `box-shadow` so remove it

```
#menu-1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); //remove box-shadow
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it only hides the problem, it doesn't solve it. If you look at the language-menu to the right the white border is still there.

Comment: but i didnt seen any white border in `language menu`